# Using SNMP to get Server Information

Tags: monitoring, snmp

I'm using SNMP to get Server Infomation.
I want to get CPU/Process type, for example : Intel (R) Pentium (R) Dual CPU E2180 @ 2.00GHz
I try very hard but I can't find suitable OID.

Can't anyone help me?

P/s : sorry about my lack Eng ability

Answer (score 0):

The [sysDescr](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1) table usually (but not always) contains information related to the machine's hardware, CPU included. However you should definitely take a look at the [hrDevice](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1) table where the hrDeviceType is *hrDeviceProcessor*, here is what I get querying my laptop:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c ******* 192.168.*.* 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1

HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr.768 = STRING: GenuineIntel: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 330  @ 2.13GHz
```

Comment: i try sysDescr table and hrDevice, but the result make me confuse.
- On my desktop (win 7) the result is : Intel (only Intel).
- On my laptop (win 7- Sony Vaio ) : Unknown processor type
- On a Solaris PC : An electric chip that makes this computer work.
- On a Linux PC : Intel

Comment: I asked this question few months ago, take a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447468/retrieve-hardware-informations-through-snmp). In few words it depends on how your hardware and OS fills the MIB table. I have a Sony Vaio as well and I get Unknown Processor if running from Windows, I get the correct value if running from Debian.